# Can't inject property, setter selector not found

Tags: ios, swift, typhoon

Using Typhoon and Swift, I am setting up my project and I have this problem. I have a class `TPLAddInteractor` this way

```
class TPLAddInteractor: NSObject, TPLAddInteractorInput {

    var output: TPLAddInteractorOutput?
    var dataManager: TPLDataManagerInterface?
}
```

My assembly looks like this

```
class TPLAddAssembly: TyphoonAssembly {

    var applicationAssembly: TPLApplicationAssembly?

    dynamic func addInteractor() -> AnyObject {

        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(TPLAddInteractor.self) {
            (definition) in

            definition.injectProperty("output", with: self.addPresenter())
            definition.injectProperty("dataManager", with: self.applicationAssembly?.dataManager())
        }
    }

    dynamic func addPresenter() -> AnyObject {

        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(TPLAddPresenter.self) {
            (definition) in

            definition.injectProperty("interactor", with: self.addInteractor())
        }
    }
}
```

And then I receive this error right after running the app:

```
reason: 'Can't inject property 'dataManager' for object '<TPL.TPLAddInteractor: 0x7ff5b2d2bcf0>'. Setter selector not found. Make sure that property exists and writable'
```

I am reading the Swift example of Typhoon and I don't see anything unusual in my code. But I am new on Swift so maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks

Comment: I'll provide a detailed answer later, but did you try marking the var dynamic?

Comment: Hi Jasper. If i mark it as dynamic the compiler says "Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C". But, if i change the type of "dataManagwr" from the TPLDataManagerInterface to the impl (TPLDataManager) and I marked it as dynamic, there is no problem at all... I think I'm missing something related with Swift :\

Comment: You have to add the '@objc' directive to Swift protocols unfortunately. It should work then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To work with Typhoon, it's necessary for Swift protocols to have the '@objc' directive. This is because Typhoon uses the Objective-C runtime as Swift has no native dynamism as yet.

This requirement is documented in the [Swift Quick Start](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Swift-Quick-Start).

Comment: protocol is already having @objc directive. Still getting problem 'Setter selector not found. Make sure that property exists and writable'

Answer (score 1):

```
//Inject as follows it will give a warning but its working for me:
definition?.injectProperty(Selector(("cityInfo")), with: self.coreAssembly.cityInfo())
```